Дополнения vscode для Unity
я учу unity и c#. пишу коды Vscode. у меня не подсвечиваются методы и нет подсказок. все голубым цветом.
я установил дополнения:
c#
Debugger for Unity
Unity Tools
подскажите что надо еще установить. пожалуйста.

Редактор Visual studio?

При установке любого релиза движка в Unity Hub, тебе предлагают установить Visual Studio с всем необходимым. Сами Microsoft позволяют Unity Technologies устанавливать через свой лончер Visual Studio и поддерживают это. Даже если установить его самостоятельно, в Visual Studio Installer, среди компонентов есть инструменты для Unity3D. Что тебе нужно, так это не ссать против ветра. В Install, у любого скаченного релиза нажми шестерёнка/Add modules и поставь VS! VS Code это блокнот на стеройдах, а не IDE!

У меня в VS Code стоят расширения: .NET Install Tool, C#, C# Dev Kit, IntelliCode for C# Dev Kit, Unity. В самом редакторе Unity в Package Manager стоит Visual Studio Editor (в блоке Engineering), у него обязательно нужно версию до актуальной поднять на вкладке Version History, без этого не работает подсветка.
